# Injecting Python Code into Process

Tags: c#, python, code-injection

I want to Inject Python Code into a process and It seems to be crashing my process when it injects. I do not get any errors on my own program but the target process stops working. The called unmanaged APIs have not given me any errors and seem to have carried out their execution properly.

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess,IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress,IntPtr lpParameter,uint dwCreationFlags, out uint lpThreadId);
    [Flags]
    enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VMOperation = 0x00000008,
        VMRead = 0x00000010,
        VMWrite = 0x00000020,
        DupHandle = 0x00000040,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
    [Flags]
    public enum AllocationType
    {
        Commit = 0x1000,
        Reserve = 0x2000,
        Decommit = 0x4000,
        Release = 0x8000,
        Reset = 0x80000,
        Physical = 0x400000,
        TopDown = 0x100000,
        WriteWatch = 0x200000,
        LargePages = 0x20000000,
        VIRTUAL_MEM = (0x1000 | 0x2000)
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum MemoryProtection
    {
        Execute = 0x10,
        ExecuteRead = 0x20,
        ExecuteReadWrite = 0x40,
        ExecuteWriteCopy = 0x80,
        NoAccess = 0x01,
        ReadOnly = 0x02,
        ReadWrite = 0x04,
        WriteCopy = 0x08,
        GuardModifierflag = 0x100,
        NoCacheModifierflag = 0x200,
        WriteCombineModifierflag = 0x400,
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x00000040
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, UIntPtr dwSize, uint dwFreeType);
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject( IntPtr handle,Int32 milliseconds);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    private void InjectCode(string shellcode = "print('Hello, World!')")
    {
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName == "Toontown")
            {
                int shellcode_length = shellcode.Length;
                IntPtr h_process = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, (int)proc.Id);
                IntPtr shellcode_address = (IntPtr)VirtualAllocEx(h_process, (IntPtr)0, (uint)shellcode_length, AllocationType.VIRTUAL_MEM, MemoryProtection.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[shellcode.Length * sizeof(char)];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(shellcode.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                UIntPtr bytesout;
                uint t_id;

                bool Written = WriteProcessMemory(h_process, shellcode_address, bytes, (uint)shellcode_length, out  bytesout);
                IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)CreateRemoteThread(h_process, (IntPtr)null, 0, (IntPtr)shellcode_length, (IntPtr)shellcode_address, 0, out t_id);
                int Result = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10 * 1000);
                if (Result == 0x00000080L || Result == 0x00000102L || Result == 0xFFFFFFFF)
                {
                    if (hThread != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(hThread);
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                VirtualFreeEx(h_process, shellcode_address, (UIntPtr)0, 0x8000);
                if (hThread != null)
                {
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you may see, I have saved the returned values of the unmanaged API into variables which I used to see if it was working or not, it seemed to be doing fine but it crashes the target process, logs haven't recorded any errors related to it.
Can managed programs inject into unmanaged processes? Am I casting wrong variable types? Is the shellcode translated into byte array incorrectly? Please let me know, thanks.

EDIT: It crashes at CreateRemoteThread

Comment: Have you considered running the python in process using DLR and IronPython?

Comment: No, can you explain how this may help injecting code? Dynamic Language Runtime used to inject, I haven't used it before.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateRemoteThread` creates a native thread in another process, the start address it receives must point to valid machine code or the thread will crash the process.

The scenario you describe is different, you want to instruct the Python interpreter of another process to execute some code. This can be done, but it is different and considerably more difficult.

Inject a native library into the other process which does two things:

- setup the Python interpreter
- setup some means of interprocess communication (IPC)

Use the IPC to send the Python code you want to execute to the other process and the code in the library you injected then executes that code using the Python interpreter.

You can find an example of how to inject a DLL into another process [in this Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run some arbitrary Python code from .net. Now you are trying to invoke the Python interpreter to actually do this.

The cons of doing this are:-

- It is complicated as you found out.
- Interprocess communication makes it even harder, as you move bytes across the boundary
- Then you need to parse the information that you get from each side into something that makes sense (probably using some kind of XML)
- Finally with all the above overhead its slow

Now one way around this is to invoke the python program directly within .net. Now I have never done so in my life AND I have never seen a python in my life (except maybe the type that hisses). Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx, unfortunately it looks like they are storing the python in a file and invoking it there. However I am sure you can invoke code stored as a string.

The main disadvantage of using the DLR implementation of python is that you are relying on a third party to get the Python -> CLR translation correct. But I think IronPython is a microsoft sponsored open source project.

For more information see: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/